# In vanilla forum, message time and post time is displayed wrong

Tags: php, timezone, vanilla-forums

In forum whenever anybody messages or posts something, the time is displayed wrong, it is showing half an hour back time. The default timezone is set as "UTC" and for India timezone is "UTC+05:30". I tried to change it to "UTC+05:30" and "Asia/Kolkata" but it didn't work. I think this function **date_default_timezone_set()** will not accept "UTC+05:30" but "Asia/Kolkata" is also not working for me.

Comment: Why is it not working? `Asia/Kolkata` is `UTC+5:30` all year, and has been since year 1945. You can check that like this: `print_r((new DateTimezone('Asia/Kolkata'))->getTransitions());`.

Comment: Can you paste any code, where it demonstrates how it works, and how it should work?

Comment: It is known issue and it is not fixed

https://github.com/vanilla/vanilla/issues/1626